# How to get Array from Array String in JavaScript or AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Initially I have variable that contains string data

```
var stringArray = "[{'middleName':'T','lastName':'TEST5LAST','occupation':'QA','homeAddressZipcode':'85001','entitySequenceNumber':7,'homeAddressCity':'PHOENIX','ssn':'111111115','cellPhone':'4807363273','employer':'ABC','workPhoneExtension':'5555','entityType':'JOINT','homePhone':'4807363272','identificationType':'0','email':'FIRST5.LAST5@TEST.COM','workPhone':'4807363274','firstName':'TEST5FIRST','homeAddressStreet':'8000','homeAddressState':'AZ'}]";
```

Is there a function in JavaScript or AngularJS that will allow me to build a real JavaScript Array like this?:

```
var realArray = [
  {
     "middleName":"T",
     "lastName":"TEST1LAST",
     "occupation":"HR",
     ...
  },
  {
     "middleName":"T",
     "lastName":"TEST5LAST",
     "occupation":"QA",
     ...
  },
  ...
];
```

Comment: Your sample string has a closing `]` but no opening `[`, btw.

Comment: native function in AngularJS would be [`angular.fromJson(stringArray);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)

Comment: Yes, S McCrohan, you are right. It was my typo. Corrected it.

Comment: Your Array contains only one element. Do you confirm ?

Comment: In current example yes, but it should handle multiple elements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
realArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(stringArray)` return JSON object